# Convert PostgreSQL SQL dump to PostgreSQL custom-format dump

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

My use case is the following:

- I have PostgreSQL dumps made with `pg_dump -F p` (plain-text SQL script file), which I have no control over how they're made
- I like `pg_restore` flexibility (--no-owner, --data-only, --clean, etc)

I know I should use `psql` with plain-text SQL dumps, but ***is there any way to convert the SQL dump into a PostgreSQL custom-format dump*** so I can use pg_restore, or some way of getting all its options?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: No, you can not convert it. The only way to create a dump in custom format is to use `pg_dump -F c`

Comment: I stand by with mr Horse with no name, u cant really do that, except for dump obviously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the other answers/comments mentioned, you can't convert it directly. What you should do is create a temporary database from the sql backup file and use pg_dump to make a custom format from it.

Check that the sql backup is not a "clean" restore file, meaning it doesn't drop the database at the top of the file. If it is, remove the "DROP DATABASE dbase"..

Create a temp database:

```
psql
CREATE DATABASE mytempdb;
\q
```

Then restore the backup you have to it:

```
psql mytempdb < my_database_backup.sql
```

Note: This is why you do NOT want the "drop database..." line in the top of the sql file. It will drop your original database instead.

Dump it as custom format:

```
pg_dump mytempdb -Fc -f custom_format.dump
```

Comment: It would be good to delete this temporary database when you're done: `psql --command="DROP DATABASE mytempdb;"`